# How to use NSRegularExpression in Swift 2.0 in xcode 7

Tags: ios, regex, swift2, xcode7

//The error is here `let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(<img.*?src=\")(.*?)(\".*?>)", options: nil, error: nil)`

//The error is:***

> cannot find an initializer for type nsregularexpression that accept an
>   argument of type (pattern: string,ption:nil,error:nil)

Comment: The signature in Swift 2 is: `init(pattern pattern: String, options options: NSRegularExpressionOptions) throws`.

Answer (score 10):

There are 2 changes with regards to the syntax in Swift 2.0: (1) you wrap the call in a `try ... catch` block instead of supplying an `error` parameter; and (2) `options` should be a `Set`, not a numerical `or` of the individual options.

In your case the code should look like this:

```
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(<img.*?src=\")(.*?)(\".*?>)", options: [])
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

If you know that your pattern always succeeds, you can shorten it like this:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(<img.*?src=\")(.*?)(\".*?>)", options: [])
```

Now if you want to set options to your pattern, you can do this:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(<img.*?src=\")(.*?)(\".*?>)", options: [.CaseInsensitive, .AnchorsMatchLines])
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift2. You need use `do` `try` `catch` for error handling.

```
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(<img.*?src=\")(.*?)(\".*?>)", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)
}catch {
// Handling error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**NSRegularExpression in Swift 2.0 in xcode 7**

```
 extension String {
     func isEmail() throws -> Bool {
         let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", options: [.CaseInsensitive])

        return regex.firstMatchInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, characters.count)) != nil
}
}
```

> Then when you want to call the method, do it from within a do block and catch the error that comes out.

```
do {
      try "person@email.com".isEmail()
   } catch {
      print(error)
   }
```