# Error after updating to xcode 7 : Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSRegularExpression' with an argument list of type

Tags: regex, swift2, xcode7

Get following error after updating xcode:
"Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSRegularExpression' with an argument list of type '(pattern: String, options: NilLiteralConvertible, error: NilLiteralConvertible)'"

Following is code which cause error:

```
        func applyStylesToRange(searchRange: NSRange) {
    let normalAttrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody)]
    // iterate over each replacement
    for (pattern, attributes) in replacements {
        let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: nil, error: nil)!
        regex.enumerateMatchesInString(backingStore.string, options: nil, range: searchRange) {
            match, flags, stop in
            // apply the style
            let matchRange = match.rangeAtIndex(1)
            self.addAttributes(attributes, range: matchRange)

            // reset the style to the original
            let maxRange = matchRange.location + matchRange.length
            if maxRange + 1 < self.length {
                self.addAttributes(normalAttrs, range: NSMakeRange(maxRange, 1))
            }
        }
    }
```

error is at this line:- let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: nil, error: nil)!
please suggest me how to resolve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use NSRegularExpression in Swift 2.0 in xcode 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406706/how-to-use-nsregularexpression-in-swift-2-0-in-xcode-7)

Answer (score 0):

Check out a new initialiser

```
public init(pattern: String, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions) throws
```

It means now you must pass an `options` argument and be ready to catch an error. Example:

```
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "pattern", options: .CaseInsensitive)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The initalizer is now throwable and needs an option:

```
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "YouPattern", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Hi @joern: I tried your solution and it work for me ,but now I am getting error at this line:   "regex.enumerateMatchesInString(backingStore.string, options: nil, range: searchRange) " .  could you please help me to resolve this code according to swift 2.

Comment: That is because the options can no longer be `nil`, you have to pick an option.